# get value from a tag

Tags: jquery

I have html structure  like this:

```
<div class="dk_options">
   <ul class="dk_options_inner">
      <li class="dk_option_current"><a data-dk-dropdown-value="">Select State</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="1">AK</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="2">AL</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="3">AR</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="4">AZ</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="5">CA</a></li>
      <li class=""><a data-dk-dropdown-value="6">CO</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I want to get the value of a tag attribute data-dk-dropdown-value. my code is always show empty

```
var a=jQuery('#dk_container_businessState .dk_options ul li a').attr('data-dk-dropdown-value');
alert(a);
```

Comment: data("dk-dropdown-value") would likely work better and at least work as intended by the data attribute

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
jQuery('#dk_container_businessState .dk_options li').each(function(){
  var a = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('data-dk-dropdown-value');
  alert(a);
});
```

Instead use `.data()` for better use:

```
var a = jQuery(this).find('a').data('dk-dropdown-value');
```

[**Read for data-* custom attributes**](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

Answer (score 1):

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/gUYX6/

```
 jQuery('#dk_container_businessState .dk_options li').each(function(){
  var a = jQuery(this).find('a').data('dk-dropdown-value');
  alert(a);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use attr, there is a [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function for this. The right way to select the data of an element is:

```
var val = $('.dk_options ul li a').data('dk-dropdown-value');
```

To set data use:

```
$('.dk_options ul li a').data('dk-dropdown-value', 'value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dk_options .dk_options_inner li a').each(function(){
       alert($(this).attr('data-dk-dropdown-value'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your selector is collecting all the elements in your list, but the .data() method only acts on the first matched element. The value of that element's data-dk-dropdown-value attribute is "".

If you want all of the values for each matched element, try something like this:

```
var a=[];
jQuery('#dk_container_businessState .dk_options ul li a').each(function () {
  a.push($(this).data('dk-dropdown-value'));
});
alert(a);
```